# Unity ARFoundation move existing gameobjects

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am new to **unity** and **arfoundation** and trying to implement a basic example where i can place multiple gameobjects on the detected place(horizontal) and move a particular gameobject.

I have achieved to place multiple gameobjects. Here is my code for the same:

```
touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // private Touch touch;

    if (Input.touchCount < 0 || touch.phase != TouchPhase.Began)
        return;

    if (isPointerOverUI(touch)) return;

    Ray ray = arCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);

    if(_arRayCastManager.Raycast(ray, _hits))
    {
        Pose pose = _hits[0].pose;
        Instantiate(DataHandler.Instance.gameobject, pose.position, pose.rotation);
    }
```

What i want to do now is to move a selected/clicked gameobject. Can someone help me to resolve the same.

Comment: You can use [XR Interaction Toolkit](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@0.9/manual/index.html). It provides lots of gestures & interactions in AR Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code:

```
        Vector3 v3;

         if (Input.touchCount != 1) {
             dragging = false; 
             return;
         }

         Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
         Vector3 pos = touch.position;

         if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
             RaycastHit hit;
             Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(pos); 
             if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && (hit.collider.tag == "Draggable"))
             {
                 Debug.Log ("Here");
                 toDrag = hit.transform;
                 dist = hit.transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
                 v3 = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, dist);
                 v3 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(v3);
                 offset = toDrag.position - v3;
                 dragging = true;
             }
         }
         if (dragging && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
             v3 = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, dist);
             v3 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(v3);
             toDrag.position = v3 + offset;
         }
         if (dragging && (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)) {
             dragging = false;
         }
```

This should detect if you are touching an object and if so, it will drag it around.